# How to check if user left register field empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, count, null

I have registration form. In this case it will simply contain USERNAME and PASSWORD.

When I created the table in SQL Server, i put both columns on NOT NULL but when I try to register without entering either username or password there are no errors and my forms 'registrates' new user for example without password (if I didn't enter password).

Here is my code so if anyone can help me with that problem, and also to say if anything other is wrong/poorly written with the code because I'm new in all of this. I think I did good on SQL injection problem but you never know. Thank you very much on your reply.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HOME-PC;Initial Catalog=TestDB1;Integrated Security=True");

    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.users (uUsername, uPassword) VALUES (@uUsername, @uPassword)";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uUsername", textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uPassword", textBox2.Text);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("OK");

        this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDB1DataSet.users);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Check if `textBox1.Text` and `textBox1.Text` are null or empty and if they are don't run the SQL command at all.

Comment: Do you have the option of using Entity Framework, I'd highly recommend using that instead of embedding your own queries.  It will handle more injection scenarios than you'll think of, not to mention will update over time as new ones are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood this correctly, you have an application written in C# that interacts with an SQL Server back end.

You should be able to add a check in the C# code to check if the text boxes are empty or not when you click on the button.  My C# is very rusty but it could be done thus:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || string.sNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text)) 
{
    messagebox.show("Invalid entry"); 
}
```

Sadly I don't have Visual Studio to check this, but I'd check the text boxes aren't empty before doing the SQL stuff.

Also I'd change the name of your textboxes to something you'll remember, otherwise you'll find it a nightmare when it comes to maintaining your code.

Comment: This looks like java, not c#, String.IsNullOrEmpty(username.Text).

Comment: Apologies, now fixed.  Thanks for spotting that one.

Comment: @Welshboy - yes I get what you ment so I changed it into c#
@ Marius Bancilla - thank you very much
@ jtimperley - thank you, I will re-write it and use the option of 'using', I've read about it but only recently so I'm still learning to use it

Comment: yes it works thank you. I've also added the textbox1.clear(); and textbox2.clear();

Comment: Yes, and thank you all. It was worth all the bad reputation points I've got ;)